# Dynamically Add iFrame to a Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I need to generate a composite page made up of other pages in our system.

Is it possible for me to dynamically add iFrames to a page, each with its own src pointing to different URLs which are determined on the fly? If so, is there a preferred method to this?

Otherwise I need to refactor the other pages into user controls so I can add them as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'd seriously consider revising your pages to usercontrols if you'd like the "pages" to interact with each other. But for the question itself: you could add LiteralControls to your page (containing the iFrames) or to a placeholder.

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe src='mypage.aspx'></iframe>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this the same way you dynamically add any .net control to a page, but you need to add an [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Document Object Model (DOM) / Javascript [1,2] to add iframes to your page. If you'd better like c# you'll have to postback before modifying the document I think (I'm not an expert in c# / asp).

- [1] http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics
- [2] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp